# Portable library service reference: type or namespace name 'schema' could not be found

Tags: wcf, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, windows-store-apps, portable-class-library

I have a portable class library that targets: .NET 4.5, Windows Phone 8 and Windows Store Apps.

I added a service reference to a WCF project built with .NET 4.0.

I received the following warning and error:

> Warning   1   Custom tool warning: Service proxy generation failed. Proxy
>   requires type 'System.Xml.XmlElement' which is not supported in
>   portable libraries.

and

> type or namespace name 'schema' could not be found

What can be wrong here? Is there a workaround this issue without modifying the WCF project?